# Check the owner of an NFT

Tags: nft, owner

I'm currently developing an NFT Marketplace on Solana, by using Anchor. In my `create_listing` function, I need to check that a person that want to list the NFT actually holds the NFT they want to list. So how can I do that? Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 3):

Easiest to use the DAS API, Helius has a solid doc for this. getAsset method contains owner information: https://docs.helius.dev/compression-and-das-api/digital-asset-standard-das-api/get-asset

Comment: the option to do this without an indexer is basically calling getProgramAccounts on the token account program to see who has a balance of 1 filtered by nft's mint. but this will be very slow to do many times

Comment: Do we have any better approach to do this, sir? Also, I need a method to check in the program (written in Rust), but this method seems to use JS script instead, right sir?